# Приведите свой пример для object pool

Tags: php, ооп, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть известный нам паттерн object pool. Его рекомендуют как performance паттерн, потому что можно сразу проинициировать N тяжелых объектов, и дальше работать с ними.

Во многих ресурсах по PHP именно на это делают упор, и , соответственно, мне интересно:
что же на практике может быть этот объект, что в вебе его круто было бы синициировать сразу.

ИЛИ,

приведите пример со своей практики, какая у вас была задача, и чего вы добились благодаря внедрению пула объектов

P.S я знаю как его использует game-dev. Так же, видел реализацию на js, с примером, когда код использовался в ограниченной по памяти среде.

но, для себя пока кроме пула воркеров ничего внятно придумать не смог.

Comment: `во многих ресурсах по PHP именно на это делают упор`  враньё. В php делают упор в неинициализации элементов до момента использования (т.н. lazy-loading). А пул используют в java для подключения к бд. Т.к. само подключение занимает продолжительное время, то лучше сделать его заранее.

Comment: @ArchDemon ок, тогда вопрос такой: ваш пример, насколько я понимаю, включает в себя инициализацию синглтона. Мы толком не работаем с обьетами, мы работаем с одним единственным обьектом, что похожое на извращенный object pool. Можете пояснить подробнее, если я не прав в суждениях?

Comment: ну типа да, это ранняя инициализация, но это сложно назвать пулом, по крайней мере пока что

Comment: Если говорить о пуле соединений в java, то там полноценный пул. Используется из разных потоков для одновременного обслуживания запросов к БД. С одной стороны чтобы не тратить время на соединение с БД, с другой, чтоб ограничить количество активных запросов выполняемых в БД.

Comment: @ArchDemon ну lazy-loading и пул объектов не обязательно взаимоисключающие понятия. Обычно объекты создаются лениво, но после использования не уничтожаются, а возвращаются в пул. В пуле не обязательно сразу все инициализировать, главная выгода от повторного использования. Хотя иногда можно и сразу создать - "подогреть пул", чтоб latency первых запросов был более предсказуемым.

Comment: ок, это всё про java, в PHP пишут что паттерн даёт нам возможность создать сразу  N тяжелых/неудобных обьектов, которые потом можно использовать. Что имеется ввиду, когда говорится тяжелый PHP обьект?

Comment: пока что на ум приходит какой-то большой агрегат, который собирается с дюжины джоинов в таблице за секунд 3-5+, и с которого мы в дальнейшем будем производить бизнес логику. Это корректный пример?

Comment: Назначение пула - использовать объект и вернуть его назад, чтобы параллельные процессы могли его использовать повторно. PHP синхронный язык, в таком виде пул не нужен. Хотите просто использовать тяжелые объекты повторно? Сделайте класс, который будет кешировать эти объекты. При первом получении - лезть в базу. При повторном - доставать закешированный в памяти. Или вы реально используете асинхронность в PHP?

Comment: @TotalPusher, нет, пока нет))

Answer (score -1):

на сколько мне известно пул объектов применяется в OpenCart, Fat-Free Framework и т.д.

для меня это вполне удобный паттерн.

вот он реализован в OpenCart

```php
final class Registry {
    private $data = array();

    public function get($key) {
        return (isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : NULL);
    }

    public function set($key, $value) {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function has($key) {
        return isset($this->data[$key]);
    }
}
// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);

// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);

// Request
$request = new Request();
$registry->set('request', $request);

// Response
$response = new Response();
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$response->setCompression($config->get('config_compression'));
$registry->set('response', $response);

// Document
$registry->set('document', new Document());
```

и в самом контроллере они вызывается примерно так

```php
class ControllerCommonHome extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_title'));
        $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->config->get('config_title');

     $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }

}
```

подобных примеров можно найти кучу если захотеть.

Comment: простите, не соглашусь с вашим примером. Ваш класс registry являет собой словарь. Он не следит, сколько уже обьектов в пулле, и соответственно никакой логики вокруг взятия нового обьекта с пулла нету(в плане что делать? отдать/не отдать/создать новый/выбросить исключение что все объекты заняты, и т.п)